# String to Integer Returning 0

Tags: php, type-conversion

I am converting , through type cast , through intval() and other procedures , but what is returned from **$Id (string :eg "99973132")** is always **0**. I will be grateful if anyone can guide me.The value that I am converting from string to int is of length **99973132(all the values are close to this)** . I have crossed checked . The value returned in **$Id** is **99973132** but conversion results in **0**

```
    <?php
    require_once('../SchemaBuilder/Dbconfig.php');
    require_once('../SchemaBuilder/NativeConfiguration.php');
    $servername = MYSERVERNAME;
    $username = MYUSERNAME;
    $password = MYPW;
    $dbname = MYDBNAME;
     // Create connection
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

    if(!file_exists($_FILES['csvdata']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csvdata']['tmp_name']))
    { echo "no file";
       echo "<br> No file Selected press back to try again!!<br>";

    }
          else
            {

   $content= file_get_contents($_FILES["csvdata"]["tmp_name"]);
   $content= file_get_contents($_FILES["csvdata"]["tmp_name"]);
   $lines = explode("\n", $content);

  $i = 0;//initialize

    foreach($lines as $value)
    { 
      if($i != 0)
      {
 $cols[$i] = explode("\t", $value);

 if(isset($cols[$i][9]))
 {     $id=$cols[$i][0] +0;


    $query = "INSERT INTO csvdata(Id,UserName)
    VALUES(".$i.", '".$cols[$i][9]. "')" ;


    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "New record created successfully".'<br>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error.'<br>';
    }
   $x++;
 }

       }

       $i++;
    }

  $conn->close();


    }
    ?>
```

**Edit :** I am loading a .tsv file , after that parsing each line by skiping first line , then exploding by **\t** . fetching first attribute which is in **$id** and converting it to integer . but its not converted and gives 0

Comment: Why are you checking that `$cols[$i][9]` is set, but then taking the value from `$cols[$i][0]` instead?

Comment: And why do you set `$varrr` but never use it?

Comment: And why do you convert _at all_ when it looks like all you want to do is stuff it into a sql query where the type does not matter at all?

Comment: let me add complete code

Comment: @Bobulous I have checked that attribute because it is compulsory